# How to write Regex for String 1111111 or 0000000

Tags: java, regex

How can we write these Regular Expressions 
minimum 7-time repetition with "OR operator" condition

String regex = "(1111111|0000000)";

Any other best way to write this.

Comment: Have you read the [relevant documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Comment: `a.equals("1111111") || a.equals("0000000")` this seems like a bad place for a regular expression to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - If only regexes were Turing complete.  Then we could do everything with regexes ... that someone else writes for us :-)

Answer (score 4):

Capture the initial digit in a group, then backreference that group 6 or more times:

```
([01])\1{6,}
```

If you actually only want to match exactly 7 digits, no more, then remove the `,`.

Comment: It's not working because I am asking another way to write this.
   ---       "0{7,}|1{7,}"   is Answer

Comment: You asked for another way to write `(1111111|0000000)`, and `([01])\1{6,}` is indeed another (and more correct) way to write it - can you explain why it's not sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Simple like that:

`0{7,}|1{7,}`

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    String zeros = "0000000";
    String ones = "1111111";
    String eights = "8888888";
    String shuffle = "6516516";

    System.out.println(zeros.matches("0{7,}|1{7,}")); // true
    System.out.println(ones.matches("0{7,}|1{7,}")); // true
    System.out.println(eights.matches("0{7,}|1{7,}")); // false
    System.out.println(shuffle.matches("0{7,}|1{7,}")); // false
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right as the OP did say _minimum_ 7-time repetition.

Comment: Thank Rhuan Karlu. 
That's was the thing for I was looking.

Comment: @mahendraparmar please accept the answer, I'm doing a job interview and my stackoverflow points count a lot. :)